# how to get value from file before first commit

Tags: git, gitlab, continuous-integration

I have a command which returns me a "version" from api.yaml file:

```
branch=$(grep 'version:' api.yaml | awk  '{print $2}')
echo "Branch version is:" $branch
```

also I have a command which returns me a "Version" value for a merge request source branch name:

```
origin=$(git show "origin/${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME}" -- api.yaml | grep version | grep '^\-' | awk  '{print $3}')
echo "Origin branch is:" $origin
```

When I change a version and do a commit I get a currnet version, that is fine!
But command which should return me source branch name value, returns me value of last commit and not the first.
So, when I have multiple commits, I always get the latest commit version and not the first versio.

what should be the command that returns me first value of "version" in branch?

Comment: To make sure I understand the problem correctly... You essentially want the original contents of `api.yaml` as it was before the changes in the MR (so you can retrieve the version from it). Does that sound right?

Comment: There is no commit before the first commit. That's what makes it the "first commit". A branch name identifies the *last* commit in the branch, but from there, Git works backwards until there are no more commits. The last commit in this "working backwards" process is by definition the first commit, and there's nothing earlier. There is no automatic marker "branch began here". You can drop your own marker, and do whatever you like with that, of course, but you must remember to do that.

Comment: Yes, I need "version" number in a moment of branch name creation. Then I would compare that "version" number with "version" in master branch and if there is a diference i would ask user to rebase his own branch.  What would be the command to get that version in a moment of branch creation?